# NEO4J - Return node based on max or min values

Tags: networking, graph, neo4j, cypher

I constructed a network with the following command:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///trial.csv' AS row
MERGE(s:Person {id: row.Sender})
MERGE(r:Person {id: row.Receiver})
SET r.goodness = row.`goodness`
MERGE (s)-[hr:SENDS_TO]->(r)
SET hr.fairness = row.fairness
```

and I want to return the node with the highest goodness or fairness relationship. I could only use this:

```
MATCH (s:Person)
RETURN max(s.goodness)
```

to return the maximum goodness score
and used this to return person but it wouldnt work:

```
MATCH (s:Person)
WHERE s.goodness = max(s.goodness)
return s
```

Any idea where I am going wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have forgotten to turn your goodness/fairness into numbers! with `toInteger` or `toFloat`

Yes because you're doing an aggregation which is only possible in a projection (WITH or RETURN) not in an expression. You have two options:

```
MATCH (s:Person)
RETURN s
ORDER BY s.goodness DESC LIMIT 1
```

(which could benefit from index based ordering if you're on 3.5 and have an index on s.goodness and use this statement).

```
MATCH (s:Person)
WHERE s.goodness > 0
RETURN s
ORDER BY s.goodness DESC LIMIT 1
```

Or you can use this approach which is a bit more expensive and also needs an index on goodness to run well.

```
MATCH (s:Person)
WITH max(s.goodness) as max
MATCH (s:Person) WHERE s.goodness = max
RETURN s
```

(which might return more than one person)

Comment: Thank you! is it possible to also query the fairness? which is a float property between nodes?

Comment: also is it possible to query, for example, maximum goodness score using the above code but limit the fairness values from 0.5 to 1